# Mapping my Spring boot application to a HTML file on local host

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to link a HTML page to my Spring boot application.

I've connected a SQL DB to it, and have set up the needed controllers, but cannot map the HTML page to the local host.

Here is the GIT for the project.

https://github.com/ThierryLucDenichaud/SpringBoot_SQL_SPRING_HTML.git

Comment: I ran your code and its displaying `working` on `http://localhost:8080/`. How are you running your project?

Comment: yes the updated version works, finally got it, hitting localhost:8080/index.html finally works, and can reach my db vai my mapped getAlbums method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a configuration file that look like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("indexPage.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

}
```

This will create a default controller for serving your index.html on `/`.

A little recommendation, change `indexPage.html` to `index.html` and also `setViewName("indexPage.html")` to `setViewName("index.html")` as `index.html` is usually the default in most systems and frameworks.

**EDIT**

I just noticed your `public` folder is in `src/main` while it should be in `src/main/resources`. spring boot won't handle your static files unless they are first in `src/main/resources` then in `public` as the default folder that is exposed to the outside world.

Also in `Java` you should place classpath resources in `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` for tests.

Comment: Amazing, got it to work. Is there anyway, I can private email you, would love to ask you, 1 or 2 things in regards to spring boot.

Comment: Place your email here and ill contact you, I prefer not to publish my email. Also if it helped and solved the problem you can mark it as Accepted so others can make use of the answer as well.